# The targetNamespace parameter should be the same value as the targetNamespace of the schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, xsd-validation

I am getting this error when I read an xml file with inline schema validation. The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SysConfig xmlns="PM-NameSpace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SysConfig.xsd">
...
</SysConfig>
```

The XSD file is in the same folder as the XML file and is called "SysConfig.xsd" and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="PM-NameSpace" targetNamespace="PM-NameSpace">
...
</xs:schema>
```

I want to do inline schema validation in code, so my C# looks like this:

```
XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(handler);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sysConfigPath, xmlReaderSettings);
XmlDocument sysConfigXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
sysConfigXmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
```

As soon as Load is called (last line) the validation event handler is invoked, the actual message being:

**Cannot load the schema for the namespace ' ' - The targetNamespace parameter ' ' should be the same value as the targetNamespace 'PM-NameSpace' of the schema.**

which seems to indicate that something is using the default ('') namespace, but I have very carefully specified the xlmns and the target namespaces. I don't understand what the error message means by "The targetNamespace parameter ' ' ..." - the targetNamespace *attribute* is specified and is not blank (' ') - I don't know what a "*parameter*" is in xml terms - or is it referring to something in (or missing from) the C# code?
Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not encountered this issue, but I believe the reason this is happening is that `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` is for actually indicating the XSD location for XML that has **no** namespace.  Your XML actually has a namespace, so I believe you should replace that attribute with:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="PM-NameSpace SysConfig.xsd"
```

Comment: The logic is sound, but sadly this simply changes the error message to:

Comment: Looks like your comment might have been cut off.

Comment: Yes. The new error message is a monster: "Multiple definition of element 'PM-NameSpace:Validation' causes the content model to become ambiguous. A content model must be formed such that during validation of an element information item sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly or implicitly therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence." Out of characters and time (in UK). Thanks. Back Monday.

Comment: It sounds like the new problem lies deeper in your XSD file. It sounds like you have more than one definition for an element called "Validation". That is, more than one `<xsd:element name="Validation">` in there.

Comment: Actually I think this may be a whole other error in my xml/xsd (although Visual Studio 2008 isn't highlighting it), in which case you may indeed have answered the question as posted. Many thanks for that. I still need a bit of guidance on how to "accept" answers and improve my rating please.

Comment: This is what I said above regarding accepting answers: "According to the FAQ, there should be a grey checkmark next to each answer of which you are able to click one of your choosing: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask Though I've never asked a question here and can't say with complete certainty." Thank you very much!

Comment: The original problem seems to be solved. Please start a new thread with the new problem. You will need to show us your schema so we can help you understand why it is ambiguous.

Comment: "According to the FAQ, there should be a grey checkmark next to each answer of which you are able to click one of your choosing" - Got it. Many thanks.